# Search decoded json results for string and echo if found

Tags: php, json

I am currently trying to search some json results (SKU and ID) and if the string (the SKU) I enter is found, I would like it to show the product ID.

I am new to this so maybe I am completely on the wrong track.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

// Establish connection with TG
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer 872ed5e72dfc7e4e0adaa7c663cab7d81415078fdbe4f486d085b718c93b3eb3")
    )
);

// API URL for TG
$url = "http://api.tradegecko.com/variants";

// Get the JSON information from TG
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// Decode that motherfucker
$json = json_decode($data);
// Now for each item do something
foreach ($json->variants as $row) {
    $getsku = $row->sku;
    $getid = $row->id;  
    $check_sku = $getsku." - ".$getid;
    // show decoded results
    //echo $check_sku."<br>";

}               

// Check to see if the SKU is there
$checking = array($check_sku);
// Search results for the string
$string = 'gini-gear';
// if the SKU matches the string, echo the product ID
foreach ($checking as $product_info) {
    if (strpos($string, $product_info) !== FALSE) {
        echo "The SKU was found, the ID is ".$getid; 
        return true;
    }
}
echo "The SKU was not found, try again";
return false;

?>
```

The decoded json results are below. And so I am looking for it to fetch '6337393'. But all i get is "The SKU was not found, try again". Can anyone help?

Edit: Full list of the decoded results below. Originally pasted a few to save on space but added the full list to help understand with the var_dump.

```
VK7i-S-SHX7 - 6852445
ELE-FLWDSLR - 6852388
AO-ATOMSUN001 - 6838367
AO-ATOMCAS003 - 6838366
665/s - 6837409
shr-01-no-ff - 6830668
ELE-OFLY - 6797386
Birdy-case - 6775341
C-G-10 - 6773506
AM-NX1 - 6762963
Foam-asc02 - 6761234
sr-head-parts - 6760813
cap-5000 - 6759821
EL15P-01-XLR - 6745144
E8P-01-XLR - 6745142
E6P-01-XLR - 6745141
K5-80-KCHK - 6743911
V800-BH35 - 6722062
5d-ii/O/P-LP6e - 6721964
LM-102 - 6634658
HD-STND - 6634656
PRSO-5 - 6631822
77mm-ring - 6627149
sc-ms100 - 6627113
5000HD-plate - 6588253
Birdy+battery - 6588248
508-adaptor - 6567665
S1500-BH35 - 6531584
FW-50P - 6526057
c100-cable - 6516369
M9-LINECAM-46 - 6516352
SN2.2-WF - 6462820
7800-ST-CASE-BTY - 6443813
7800-battery - 6443812
P-18-JS - 6443811
gini-gear - 6337393
iFocus-LG - 6337392
Moza-monitor - 6337390
moza-monitor - 6337389
MOZA - 6337388
664/O/P-DU21 - 6325053
664/O/P - 6325052
RL-230-Chrgr - 6288577
FX3P-GPRO - 6288545
OCU-SSPiPAD/PROMO - 6283738
DDMOUNT-SUCTION - 6258027
VL5-KIT-BP5-S - 6257553
D-FOCUS-515 - 6257422
D-FOCUS-004 - 6230777
comfort-arm - 6216440
puing-magic-ifocus - 6214498
FCS633 - 6214488
5000-gimbal - 6201327
mb-600-flag - 6201113
HHG-01-Spare-Battery - 6174301
fc-02-parts - 6164962
VX17E-FK-USV - 6117524
IB500-S - 6117378
FH-slider - 6100252
FLY-X3-PLUS - 6100117
HHG-Clamp - 6100066
HHG-Battery - 6100033
flag-mb02 - 6070469
VB-150-chrg - 6054413
fc-02 - 6045825
vista-arm - 6027891
FLY-X3 - 6027874
A-GH4-PRO - 6027724
P-SLNG - 6015459
ZOOMH5 - 6015453
LPE6-PLATE - 6009082
F970-PLATE - 6008981
TILT-JIB T3 - 6003487
7800 - 5997221
OCU-SSPDSLR/PROMO - 5996720
MTF-BODY - 5975179
bmcc-01 - 5975163
SKU338 - 5975157
3ft-slide - 5974334
ELE-CNFLY-BMCC - 5893285
S900-BH35 - 5893217
DVC18029-BP-AB - 5893117
V1000-35BH - 5854640
9-cage-arms - 5771016
DR-MB600 - 5752097
77RING-MB600 - 5752096
FH-MB600 - 5752028
EVF4RVW - 5751693
SL-V 1200-EX - 5734649
blimp-clip - 5724769
other - 5724767
E6-coupler - 5724766
TP-5000 - 5724736
BOX01 - 5724654
WL3200 - 5724653
slide-eng-legs - 5715588
Arm-connector - 5715494
S1200-BH35 - 5715346
VK7i-E6-SHX7 - 5693352
SHX7 - 5693349
```

**EDIT:** Thanks Barmar for that! I have changed it to the following (which I think is right) but it still does not find it.

```
<?php

// Establish connection with TG
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer 872ed5e72dfc7e4e0adaa7c663cab7d81415078fdbe4f486d085b718c93b3eb3")
    )
);

// API URL for TG
$url = "http://api.tradegecko.com/variants";

// Get the JSON information from TG
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// Decode that motherfucker
$json = json_decode($data);
$checking = array();
foreach ($json->variants as $row) {
    $getsku = $row->sku;
    $getid = $row->id;  
    $check_sku = $getsku." - ".$getid;
    // show decoded results
    //echo $check_sku."<br>";
    $checking[] = $check_sku;


$string = "gini-gear";
// if the SKU matches the string, echo the product ID
//foreach ($check_sku as $product_info) {
    if (strpos($string, $check_sku) !== FALSE) {
        echo "The SKU was found, the ID is ".$getid; 
        return true;
    }
//}
echo "The SKU was not found, try again";
return false;


// End of foreach $json->variants
}
?>
```

**Edit 2**: Still getting the same return - "The SKU was not found, try again"

```
<?php

// Establish connection with TG
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer 872ed5e72dfc7e4e0adaa7c663cab7d81415078fdbe4f486d085b718c93b3eb3")
    )
);

// API URL for TG
$url = "http://api.tradegecko.com/variants";

// Get the JSON information from TG
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// Decode that motherfucker
$json = json_decode($data);
$checking = array();
foreach ($json->variants as $row) {
    $getsku = $row->sku;
    $getid = $row->id;  
    $check_sku = $getsku." - ".$getid;
    // show decoded results
    //echo $check_sku."<br>";
    $checking[] = $check_sku;

$string = "gini-gear";
foreach ($checking as $id => $product_info) {
    if (strpos($string, $product_info) !== FALSE) {
        echo "The SKU was found, the ID is ".$id; 
        return true;
    }

}
echo "The SKU was not found, try again";
return false;


// End of foreach $json->variants
}
?>
```

**Edit 3:** The var_dump gives the following. There are loads of duplicates for some reason, this is why its so long (cannot post it as its too long) but see it [here](http://returns.pearing.co.uk/test3.php)

Edit 4: I have changed the strpos but still having the same issue. Below is the corrected strpos arrangement.

```
$string = "gini-gear";
foreach ($checking as $id => $product_info) {
    if (strpos($product_info, $string) !== FALSE) {
        echo "The SKU was found, the ID is ".$id; 
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: `$checking` will just be an array with the last row of the JSON. You need to push into the array in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to the `$checking` array in the `foreach` loop. And if you want to know which ID was matched, you should make it an associative array.

```
$checking = array();
foreach ($json->variants as $row) {
    $getsku = $row->sku;
    $getid = $row->id;  
    $check_sku = $getsku." - ".$getid;
    // show decoded results
    //echo $check_sku."<br>";
    $checking[$getid] = $check_sku;

}
```

If you do it after the loop. `$check_sku` just has the value from the last row, not all the values from every row.

Then your search loop should look like:

```
foreach ($checking as $id => $product_info) {
    if (strpos($product_info, $string) !== FALSE) {
        echo "The SKU was found, the ID is ".$id; 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here's the entire script, which I've tested and it works:

```
<?php

// Establish connection with TG
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer 872ed5e72dfc7e4e0adaa7c663cab7d81415078fdbe4f486d085b718c93b3eb3")
    )
);

// API URL for TG
$url = "http://api.tradegecko.com/variants";

// Get the JSON information from TG
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// Decode it
$json = json_decode($data);
$checking = array();
foreach ($json->variants as $row) {
    $getsku = $row->sku;
    $getid = $row->id;  
    $check_sku = $getsku." - ".$getid;
    // show decoded results
    //echo $check_sku."<br>";
    $checking[$getid] = $check_sku;

}


$string = "gini-gear";
foreach ($checking as $id => $product_info) {
    if (strpos($product_info, $string) !== FALSE) {
        echo "The SKU was found, the ID is ".$id; 
        return true;
    }
}
echo "The SKU was not found, try again";
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I kept getting the last value as you stated as just didnt know why. But still not quite getting there. I have edited why question to show what I have now but still getting -> "The SKU was not found, try again?"

Comment: Why did you get rid of the `foreach` loop to search the array?

Comment: Thanks again Barmar. Now Im starting to understand. I have edited the question again because im still getting the same thing, that the SKU cannot be found. Thank you so much Barmar

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($checking)`?

Comment: Why is `$checking[$getid] = $check_sku` missing from your second edit? It still has `$checking[] = $check_sku`.

Comment: Not sure how the $getid slipped out. But have added it back in and added a var_dump so you can see. Also check what the decoded json returned above. I first didnt post all the returns because I was only searching for one product and didnt need to but now we have done the var_dump, it makes more sense to post the whole thing.

Comment: You have the arguments to `strpos` backwards!

Comment: BTW, for some reason the ID values in the JSON all end with a newline. You might want to trim that off in the first loop, with `$getid = trim($row->id)`

Comment: Why do I need to see that? The newlines aren't causing a problem. Did you fix the `strpos` issue? That should solve it.

Comment: You should also echo `<pre>` before doing `var_dump()`, so you don't lose the formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the advise on the var_dump. Have done this and its much easier to read. I have added another edit with the strpos changed round but still no luck

Comment: You didn't change the strpos.

Comment: Posted the old code, changed now and still the same

Comment: In Edit 2, you're missing the closing `}` for the first `foreach` loop.

Comment: Now I see, you have the end of that foreach at the end of the script. Why did you do that?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! The reason I did this was because I kept getting an error on the foreach and thought that this was the reason. Turns out it must have been the arrangement of the strpos. Thanks you so much!!!!!